# Delphi - Calculate Minimum Maximum and Average in items in a list

Tags: delphi

I am building a single application to Calculate Min Max and Avg of Values in a List.

It is actually Temperatures.  So I think I am Almost correct but there are 2 Errors.

```
var
  Count, Average, Sum,i, Max, Min, K   : Integer;
  Temperatures : Array of Integer;
  NoItems : Double;
begin
  Count := 0;
  Sum := 0;
  Max := 0;
  Min := 0;
  Average := 0;

  Count := lstTemp.Items.Count;

  {Calculate Sum of Values in the list}
  for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
    Sum := Sum + StrToInt(lstTemp.Items[i]);

  {Calculate Min and Max}
  SetLength(Temperatures,Count);
  for K:=0 to Count-1 do
    Temperatures[K] := lstTemp.Items[K];
  if (Temperatures[K] > Max) then
    Max := Temperatures[K];
  if (Temperatures[K] < Min) then
    Min := Temperatures[K];
  {Calculate Average}
    Average := Sum / Count;

  edtAvg.Text:=IntToStr(Average); //Display Average
  edtAvg.Text:=IntToStr(Min); //Display Minimum Temp.
  edtAvg.Text:=IntToStr(Max); //Display Maximum Temp.
end;
```

So the 2 Errors are 
Error: Incompatible types: got "AnsiString" expected "LongInt"
This is for Average := Sum / Count;
Error: Incompatible types: got "Set Of Byte" expected "Double"
This Error is for Temperatures[K] := lstTemp.Items[K];

Any Ideas how to solve this?

Sum and Count are both Integers so I dont know why it shouldnt work!

Thanks

Comment: Your biggest problem is that you have mixed all your concerns (GUI and arithmetic) into a single unholy gloop. You'll make progress when you learn how to keep them apart. In your previous question you indicated that you did not want to learn that which will limit you.

Comment: I do not believe you have given us the right description of the errors you're getting for the above code. You've declared `Average`, `Sum` and `Count` to all be Integers. So the error you should be getting on the line `Average := Sum / Count` is: "Incompatible types: **Integer** and **Extended**".

Comment: David, I never said I did not want to learn?  I said I have not yet Learned About Functions. But thanks for the response

Comment: @user2511701 You should finish reading David's comment before jumping to conclusions (the same can be said for reading error messages). David said: "you indicated that you did not want to learn **that which will limit you**" (a practical approach to learning). However, this is vastly different from "not want to learn **full stop**". Also by using the would *indicated* is very probable that is just David's _interpretation_ of something else you said - and not something you explicitly stated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a number of problems. **First**, when you write

```
for K:=0 to Count-1 do
Temperatures[K] := lstTemp.Items[K];
if (Temperatures[K] > Max) then
Max := Temperatures[K];
if (Temperatures[K] < Min) then
Min := Temperatures[K];
```

you actually do

```
for K:=0 to Count-1 do
  Temperatures[K] := lstTemp.Items[K];

if (Temperatures[K] > Max) then
  Max := Temperatures[K];
if (Temperatures[K] < Min) then
  Min := Temperatures[K];
```

which is nonsense. You want *all* these lines to be part of the `for` loop:

```
for K:=0 to Count-1 do
begin
  Temperatures[K] := lstTemp.Items[K];
  if (Temperatures[K] > Max) then
    Max := Temperatures[K];
  if (Temperatures[K] < Min) then
    Min := Temperatures[K];
end;
```

**Second**, in order for this algorithm to work, the initial value of `Min` (`Max`) needs to be larger (smaller) than the values in the list. This might work for `Max := 0`, but probably not for `Min := 0`. You need to set `Min` to a very large value before you run the loop, obviously. The best value you can use is the highest-possible signed 32-bit integer value, that is, 2^31 - 1, which is the value of the `MaxInt` constant.

**Third**,

```
Temperatures[K] := lstTemp.Items[K];
```

is probably wrong. `Temperatures` is an array of **integers**, while `lstTemp.Items[K]` is a **string** (at least according to `StrToInt(lstTemp.Items[i])`), so you need

```
Temperatures[K] := StrToInt(lstTemp.Items[K]);
```

**Fourth**, you declare `Average` as an `integer`, but it needs to be a floating-point number (obviously), like `real` or `double`.

**Fifth**,

```
edtAvg.Text:=IntToStr(Average); //Display Average
edtAvg.Text:=IntToStr(Min); //Display Minimum Temp.
edtAvg.Text:=IntToStr(Max); //Display Maximum Temp.
```

is not techncally incorrect, but will most likely not do what you want.

**Sixth**, although not an error, there is no need for you to initialise `Count` and `Average` to `0`. Finally, you only need a single `for` loop.

Comment: `StrToInt` from a list of strings which could possibly have invalid integers :( How about `StrToIntDef`?

Comment: @Jerry: That depends on where the data comes from. In this case, the OP didn't even specify the type of the input data! (Probably a `TStrings`, though.)

Comment: Also, only need one loop

Comment: @0909EM: True. But it isn't an error, and I am not really in the mood of writing a complete Delphi programming book.

Comment: Good initial value for max and min is the first value of the array.

Comment: Andreas, You dont Understand How much you helped me out. Thanks so much For your input. My program is working perfectly now!

Comment: @user2511701: Glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 3):

There is (at least in Delphi 2010 - unit Math) one function that will calculate the mean and standard deviation in one step and functions that return the minimum and maximum values in an array. BTW, Mean is the arithmetic average of all the values and is the correct term. (I copied an example that I am working on and modified to your example - it compiles at least):

```
type
  a = array of double;
var
  Temperatures : a;
  Average,stddev3, Max, Min : extended; 
  // Compiler insists on extended for these properties
begin
   Max := Math.MaxValue(Temperatures);
   Min := Math.MinValue(Temperatures);
   Math.MeanAndStdDev(Temperatures ,Average,stddev3);
end;
```

For the maximum value in an array use (it takes an array of double and returns double):

```
function MaxValue(const Data: array of Double): Double;
```

For the minimum value use the corresponding:

```
function MinValue(const Data: array of Double): Double;
```

I agree that average cannot be an integer, but there are 2 similar functions for integer arrays:

```
function MinIntValue(const Data: array of Integer): Integer; and
function MaxIntValue(const Data: array of Integer): Integer;
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, Consider using StrToIntDef (String To Integer with a Default value) instead of StrToInt (String to Integer) this will yield the following...

```
value := StrToIntDef('Abcdef', 0); // value will be zero
```

vs

```
value := StrToInt('Abcdef'); // exception
```

But the question is do you want integers or floating point values for your temperatures? (eg 1 or 1.6?) If you want floating point values, maybe use StrToFloatDef...

Second, I've seen lots of grads that use Delphi make this mistake, try to always use begin and end, it'll help... because it makes it really clear what you are doing inside a if/for/while and what you intend to do outside..

```
for i := 0 to lstTemp.Items.Count - 1 do
begin
  // Sum all the items in the list
  Sum := Sum + StrToIntDef(lstTemp.Items[i], 0);
end;
```

Next up your array is a bit pointless, the SetLength and adding items bit is OK, but its not very functional, when you could just use the items in the list. All you need to do is hang onto the max and min values.

Then your last problem is that Average isn't going to be a whole integer, its going to have a fractional part. Eg. 5 divided by 2 is 2.5, not 2 and not 3. You could use trunc to return just the integer part, or change Average so that its a floating point number...

```
for K:=0 to lstTemp.Items.Count-1 do
begin
  if (StrToIntDef(lstTemp.Items[K], 0) > Max) then
  begin
    Max := StrToIntDef(lstTemp.Items[K], 0);
  end;
  if (StrToIntDef(lstTemp.Items[K], 1000) < Min) then // note, really high number
  begin
    Min := StrToIntDef(lstTemp.Items[K], 1000);
  end;
end;

{Calculate Average}
Average := Trunc(Sum / Count); // do you really want to trunc this? I suspect not.

if Min = 1000 then // just incase
begin
  Min := 0;
end;
```

The final problem you will face is that your always setting the text of the same text box...

```
edtAvg.Text:=IntToStr(Average); //Display Average
edtMin.Text:=IntToStr(Min); //Display Minimum Temp. (I assume this is supposed to be edtMin)
edtMax.Text:=IntToStr(Max); //Display Maximum Temp. (I assume this is supposed to be edtMax)
```

I suppose the final improvement I'd make is noticing that you only need one for loop...

```
for K:=0 to lstTemp.Items.Count-1 do
begin
  // Sum all the items in the list
  Sum := Sum + StrToIntDef(lstTemp.Items[K], 0);

  if (StrToIntDef(lstTemp.Items[K], Low(Integer)) > Max) then // A really low value
  begin
    Max := StrToIntDef(lstTemp.Items[K], Low(Integer));
  end;
  if (StrToIntDef(lstTemp.Items[K], High(Integer)) < Min) then // A really high value
  begin
    Min := StrToIntDef(lstTemp.Items[K], High(Integer));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: A really high number is `MaxInt`. Hard-coding a (not very high) `1000` is a bit dangerous.

Comment: True. But it isn't an error for a temperature conversion program it might be a reasonable number, besides, I am not really in the mood of writing a complete Delphi programming book

Comment: @0909EM It's generally better to avoid making assumptions you don't have make. Even knowing the program processes temperature data is not enough to make assumptions. Is the data gathered in sunny SA, or at an Arctic testing station, or in a smelting plant?

Answer (score 2):

0909EM's reply was very well done, but I have a few disagreements. First, I don't believe there's a need to set any sentinel value at all; simply use the first temperature value. Second, if we put a Begin and End around every single line If statement we'd approach COBOL-like levels of English verbosity. As it is, it's a crying shame this simple problem takes so much code. Third, I would **not** use StrToIntDef. Remember these lines from the Zen Of Python (I don't care if you don't know Python; everyone should memorize it, at least until we get an I Ching of Intersimone):

> Errors should never pass silently.
>
> Unless explicitly silenced.

If a user passes incorrect data into the temperature stats procedure, StrToIntDef is going to silently convert these values to zeroes, an unexpected and undesired behavior.  The caller is going to get back answers that they assume are ok (because of no errors), yet will have incorrect values (especially the average). It is a far better thing to let the procedure blow up so testing will reveal the incorrect input.

I'd also replace the For loops with For...in. I banged this together:

```
program temps;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Generics.Collections, Math;

Var
  someTemps : TStringList;

Procedure TempStats(temperatures : TStringList);
  Var
    temps                      : TList<Real>;
    minTemp, maxTemp, sumTemps : Real;
    numTemps                   : Integer;
    tempStr                    : String;
    temp                       : Real;
    avgTemp                    : Real;

Begin
  numTemps := temperatures.Count;

  If numTemps > 0 then
    Begin
      temps := TList<Real>.Create;

      For tempStr in temperatures Do
        temps.Add(StrToFloat(tempStr));

      minTemp := temps[0];
      maxTemp := temps[0];
      sumTemps := 0;

      For temp in temps Do
        Begin
          minTemp := Min(minTemp, temp);
          maxTemp := Max(maxTemp, temp);
          sumTemps := sumTemps + temp;
        End;

      avgTemp := sumTemps / numTemps;

      WriteLn(avgTemp:0:2);
      WriteLn(minTemp:0:2);
      WriteLn(maxTemp:0:2);
      temps.Free;
    End
  Else
    WriteLn('No temperatures passed.');
End;


Begin
  someTemps := TStringList.Create;
  someTemps.AddStrings(TArray<String>.Create('72', '93', '84', '76', '82'));
  TempStats(someTemps);
  ReadLn;
  someTemps.Clear;
  TempStats(someTemps);
  someTemps.Free;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: Now will somebody please tell me that there's a much simpler way to do this in just a few lines? I just rewrote this in a few seconds in another language, didn't need to fight with the compiler (seriously why can't we just pass a bunch of strings to TStringList in 2013?) or worry about freeing things, and the size difference was Delphi 119 words/906 non-whitespace characters vs. 26 words/236 characters. :-( That's depressing as heck. Why don't we have Min, Max, Sum or Avg functions that can work on any list that can iterate?????? That would make this super-simple and short.

Comment: This deserves +1 just for "Errors should never pass silently". However, avoiding sentinel's is not quite as simple as stated - the first temperature value cannot be used if it doesn't exist. (I did note that you handled the edge case in code.)

Comment: @alcalde Replying to myself - found out on the Embarcadero Delphi forum that limits on Delphi generics prevent the creation of universal aggregate functions (min, max, etc.) that deal with non-objects, at least in a non-complicated way :-(

Comment: @alcalde Ok, now Nick Hodges is showing it can be done for min and max and suggesting it can be done for the others. I'll keep... myself... posted. ;-)

Comment: @Craig Young: Edge case needs to be handled differently anyway. For empty arrays any sentinel value would be wrong, as there is neither a minimum nor a maximum value in that case. In the absence of nullable values, that is, but nullable sentinels would complicate the comparisons in the loop.

Comment: @mghie I can't argue with that. If code using a fixed sentinel were already dealing with the edge-case to resolve the logic error, then there's no need to add anything to deal with the equivalent possible Range/AV error. I.e. it **would** be as simple as using the first value.

Answer (score 2):

The most important idea on how to solve this is to **read** your error messages **properly**. On a previous question you commented: "the error was saying it is an overloaded function or *something*". That attitude is not going to help you understand the problem. You need to **read** the error messages properly.

In this question you give the following description of your errors:

> So the 2 Errors are Error: Incompatible types: got "AnsiString" expected "LongInt" This is for Average := Sum / Count; Error: Incompatible types: got "Set Of Byte" expected "Double" This Error is for Temperatures[K] := lstTemp.Items[K];

However, the description does not correspond to the errors you *should be seeing* based on the code provided.

It looks like you didn't **read** your errors, and just blindly started making changes in the hopes you would accidentally do something right. Because you didn't **read** the errors, you didn't notice that they changed. So when you came to us looking for help, you provided old errors with new code or vice-versa.

If you had actually **read** your error messages properly, you might have been able to solve the problem yourself. At the least, you would have been able to ask a better question with a description that actually matched the code.

#### Average := Sum / Count;

`Average`, `Sum` and `Count` are all declared as `Integer`. The error message you *should* be getting is: "Incompatible types: **Integer** and **Extended**".

If you **read** the error message, it should give you a clue to **read** up on `Integer` and `Extended`.

The problem here is that, in maths, division produces a Rational number. And correspondingly the result of a division operation in a program is not an Integer. So you need to declare `Average` as either `Double` or `Extended`.

#### Temperatures[K] := lstTemp.Items[K];

`Temperatures` is declared as an array of `Integer`. You haven't shown the declaration of `lstTemp`, but based on other code it's one of the standard Delphi Controls that has `Items` declared as `TStrings`. So the error message you *should* be getting is: "Incompatible types: **Integer** and **string**".

If you **read** the error message, it should give you a clue to do the same thing you did 5 lines earlier.

The reason for this error is that Delphi is a "strongly typed" language. The compiler tries to prevent you from making certain kinds of mistakes because it is much better catch them early. Imagine what might happen if one of the values in `lstTemp` were `'Hello'`. That cannot be converted to an Integer; and would cause a "run-time" error in your program.

To fix this problem you need to tell the compiler: "I know the value is a string and could be any string, but I want you to convert it to an Integer". You do this by calling the `StrToInt` function. NOTE: You will still get a run time error if an invalid string is passed to the function, but by being forced to explicitly do the conversion, you can think about whether you want to do some pre-validation of your input data.

---

You asked about the errors reported by the compiler. That's just one kind of error you'll face when programming - and usually the easiest to resolve. You'll also encounter logic errors: where your program compiles successfully, but doesn't behave correctly. [Andreas's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18675342/224704) has covered those already, so I'll not repeat them.
However, I will give you some valuable advice. Once you've gotten over the hurdle of resolving compiler errors, and are able to do so easily - you need to as quickly as possible:

- Get into the habit of testing your code thoroughly.
- Learn how to use the integrated debugger.
- Learn about its limitations.
- Learn other debugging techniques: logging, profiling, pre- and post-condition checking.

---

Finally, as a response to [alcalde's rant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18677754/224704) about there not being any simple functions to get Min, Max, Sum or Avg: I offer another possible implementation.

Basically the rant was about the fact that he'd far rather write something along the lines of:

```
begin
  if (lstTemp.Count > 0) then
  begin
    edtMin.Text := lstTemp.Min;
    edtMax.Text := lstTemp.Max;
    edtAvg.Text := lstTemp.Average;
  end
  else
  begin
    ShowMessage('List is empty');
  end;
end;
```

***Obviously the above code won't compile, but with a little work we can achieve something similar.***

He's perfectly right on two counts: **(1)** that this implementation would be cleaner, much easier to maintain and with less chance of errors. **(2)** Delphi doesn't provide a way to simply do that.

In fact, if you follow a top-down design approach, this might be your initial pseudo-code. You should be taught about top-down design, if not demand your money back. :)
The whole point behind the top-down-design approach is that you're looking for an ***ideal*** implementation. You're not worrying about what is/isn't there. If the current library and tools don't provide a `Min` function, *you can write your own*.

***You are a programmer, you have the power***!

I sometimes like to call this "wishful thinking programming". You're wishing if other things were in place, I could implement the functionality much more easily like "this". Then you go about making your wish come true.

Without further ado, here's the implementation. You will need to use the Math unit.

```
type
  { We will call existing functions that take TDoubleArray as input }
  TDoubleArray = array of Double;

  TStringsHelper = class(TStrings)
  { A useful class to help us convert TStrings into TDoubleArray }
  public
    class function Using(AStrings: TStrings): TStringsHelper;
    function AsDoubleArray: TDoubleArray;
  end;

{ TStringsHelper }

function TStringsHelper.AsDoubleArray: TDoubleArray;
var
  LoopI: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Count);
  for LoopI := 0 to Count - 1 do
  begin
    Result[LoopI] := StrToFloat(Strings[LoopI]);
  end;
end;

class function TStringsHelper.Using(AStrings: TStrings): TStringsHelper;
begin
  Result := TStringsHelper(AStrings);
end;


var
  LTemperatures: TDoubleArray;
begin
  { This code is almost the same as our "ideal" implementation }
  if (lstTemp.Items.Count > 0) then
  begin
    LTemperatures := TStringsHelper.Using(lstTemp.Items).AsDoubleArray;
    edtMin.Text := FloatToStr(MinValue(LTemperatures));
    edtMin.Text := FloatToStr(MaxValue(LTemperatures));
    edtMin.Text := FloatToStr(Mean(LTemperatures));
  end
  else
  begin
    ShowMessage('List is empty');
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

What values are in lstTemp.Items[i]?
I suppose the values are integers (without floating points), because you are using IntToStr.

Average cannot be an integer. Integer is a number (4 bytes) without a floating point. A simple numbers, such as 2,3,50,1500, -100

Assume that Sum = 100, and the Count = 3.
What Average will be?

So, you have to use float variable type, Double for example.

I hope it helps...